# VoIP/SIP Secured Real Time Protocol (SRTP): Which key length is appropriate nowadays?

Tags: phone, protection, voip, sip

Many critics say that current key lengths for SRTP-encryption in popular phone apps like `Linphone` or `CSipSimple` are not sufficient anymore.

What should be a recommended key length nowadays?

Comment: *"Many critics say..."* - could you please add some sources for this claim?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: Uh, I thought people were talking about this in the Linphone mailing list. I will have a look if I can find it again!

Comment: Also some context would be helpful.  What are the current key lengths for these phones?

Comment: The encryption algorithm used would also be useful.  The default seems to be AES, but it sounds like you can substitute other algorithms as well.